# Choose only GIF from Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to choose GIF images from my device. It has a bottomsheet and on clicking on the  button I am calling `Gallery Intent` but it is showing all type of images and videos not only the GIF images.

My problem is that how to select only GIF images from the Gallery.

```
     public void chooseFile(){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/gif");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_GIF_REQUEST);
 }
```

I have also tried `intent.setType("video/gif")` but situation is same.

Comment: `image/gif` is the correct MIME type. However, that is not a "Gallery Intent" -- any activity can respond to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. My guess is that whatever activity is responding to the `Intent` has a bug.

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Any solution for this ? I am also struggling

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.setType("image/jpeg, image/png");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_GIF_REQUEST);
```

Comment: First, `setType()` does not support multiple MIME types. Second, neither of those MIME types are GIF. Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, how this would address the question.